# MongoDB: Is it possible to have shorter Id for a record or shorter unique Id for a record?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using PHP + MongoDB. Is it possible to have shorter Id for a record or shorter unique Id for a record?
When I use Id in URL, it is too long. I want it to be shorter. Please advice.

Comment: The IDs are that length for a reason. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-objectid

Comment: While not exactly your question, this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19031308/95190

Answer (score 1):

As rightly said by @sevenseacat, the [ObjectIDs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-objectid) can't be cut short.

Instead, you can always override your `_id` value to a user-defined number or string. This would allow you to have a smaller value that you can pass in a URL.